# Gradle is not downloading mapstruct dependencies

Tags: gradle, dependencies, mapstruct

I added the dependencies suggested on the [mapstruct installation guide](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/installation/) but the dependencies are not downloaded and therefore compiler cannot find the annotations.
Here are my dependencies:
[image: My dependencies]
Intellij's view for external libraries:
[image]
the dependency should appear above the mockito dependency

There are no errors, the project runs perfectly as it is, but I can't use mapstruct.
I have the mapstruct plugin installed

What have I tried so far:

- changing mapstruct version
- deleting caches
- gradle --refresh-dependencies
- gradle clean build
- and a lot of researching but I couldn't find anything.

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious here, but I can't tell what it is.

Gradle version: 6.6.1

Comment: Did you press the "Reload all Gradle projects" in IntelliJ?

Comment: I can't believe that it was that simple. It worked. Can you explain why this worked as an answer? That way I can mark it as the correct answer